# Bash does not remember commands

Tags: bash

It's well known that if you push <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys in gnome-terminal, you can move on used commands. It only works for the commands wich are introduced before closing the window, but When I close it, gnome-terminal "forget" all commands.
Also, I cannot paste text <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick answer is 'add the following to the very end of your .bashrc file':

```
shopt -s histappend
export HISTSIZE='10000'
export HISTFILE="$HOME/.bash_history"
export HISTIGNORE=cd:ls:bg:fg:exit
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
```

...Or something like it, that's directly out of my .bashrc file.

The correct answer is 'read up on the bash shell'.
I highly recommend Learning The Bash Shell (http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565923478).

Otherwise there's a lot of free material on the web to get you started, for example : 
http:www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash.html
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Also, Romanovzky and Dennis have a valid point - the file may already be there.
You might also make sure your user owns and can write to your .bash_history file :

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER $HOME/.bash_history
sudo chmod u+w $HOME/.bash_history
```

Comment: Regarding pasting: You can highlight text and then paste into terminals with Shift+Insert, or with middle-click on your mouse.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have the file `.bash_history` in your home. If not, create a new one using the command:

```
touch ~/.bash_history
```

You may also try to remove the file if it exists, using:

```
rm ~/.bash_history
```

and then create it again with the above `touch` command.

Comment: Oh, thanks bro, I had it, but I don't know how it was locked. I deleted it and created a new one, and it works nice.

Answer (score 1):

I have Maverick and in gnome-terminal I repeat old commands with the up arrow.  I can also paste text with Control-Shift-V.

Regarding pasting - what happens if you copy something from within the window with control-shift-c and then try a Control-Shift-V paste - does that work?  Or are things in your buffer outside of the window that are failing?  Does a mouse paste work (either to the Edit -> Paste button, or right-click in the window and go down to paste) - especially from material copied from within the window?  If you go to "Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts" does it have an "Edit: Paste -> Control-Shift-V" entry?

As far as history, I echo what Romanovzky asked - do you have a .bash_history file in your home directory?  Are there commands in it?  Are you the owner, and do you have permission to read the file?

Comment: I cannot paste any text (copied from anywhere) with Ctrl+Shift+V.
The entry in the right click works fine. The entries in Keyboard Shortcuts are enabled, so I do not know what's happening.